# filter out <title>

Tags: filters

Trying to remove the  from a specific page so I don't have duplicates.  Is there away to filter these out in the functions? I have already removed the canonical but wasn't able to reproduce the same with title using wp_title or wpseo_title.

```
function remove_canonical() {

    if ( is_page(12891) ) {
        add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false',  10, 1 );
        add_filter( 'wpseo_title', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'wp_title', '__return_false' );
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_canonical');
```

Comment: By 'title`, are you thinking of the text that appears above the browser page (in or near the window frame, in the tab, etc.), or the headline that typically appears below the masthead and site navigation, and above the main content?

Comment: The actual HTML title tag <title>stuff here</title>

Comment: The first two filters are Yoast things, and off-topic here. But I think returning `false` just disables them. Anyway, it probably doesn't matter. The last filter should return a string, so you probably want `'__return_empty_string'`. That said, I might imagine that returning a non-string would have the same effect. But perhaps instead it has no effect at all (that is, the string is unchanged). If it still doesn't work, I'd try changing the priority. You want this to run last, so the priority number should be large.

Comment: Well thinking through it I don't want to filter the result or replace it, I really want to disable it.  remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );  works perfectly in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the action is really what I intended as I'm not replacing the title.  changing my last line to this works for what I was intending.

remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );

Comment: at least strictly-speaking, seems like the resulting html would be invalid, 'cause it wouldn't have a `<title>`. But anyway, you may be able to achieve the equivalent by explicitly dropping theme support for the title.